# Definition of limit in multivariable calculus; alternative to the ε-δ definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, multivariable-calculus

My goal in this question is to better understand the definition of limit in multivariable calculus. I want to define the in general ambiguous expression
$$\tag{1}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=c.
$$
The normal way in calculus is to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition with open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ which can be extended to every map between two metric spaces.
$$\tag{2}
\forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0: |(x,y)-(a,b)|<\delta\implies |f(x,y)-c|<\varepsilon
$$

Having said that I would like to look at an alternative definition:
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=c$ iff for every sequence $(x_k,y_k)$ converging to $(a,b)$ for $k\to\infty$ we have
$$\tag{3}
\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k,y_k)=c.
$$

> (A) Are (2) and (3) really equivalent for two metric spaces, i.e. (2)$\iff$(3);
>
> (B) I suppose that in any case (2)$\implies$ (3), thus if (A) is not valid, I would like a counter example for the opposite direction;
>
> (C) Generalisation: Assuming (A) is valid, how back can I go in the requirement of the two topological spaces for (A) to continue to be valid? Probably the Hausdorff property is necessary (due to net/filter, topic I only very superficially), is the Hausdorff property also sufficient?

Comment: $A$ is valid. To see why $2\to 3$, note that any sequence of points towards $x,y$ are going to in progressively tighter open balls of $(x,y)$, and hence will face tighter epsilon bounds around $c$. To see why $3\to 2$, if there is a sequence that doesn't converge to $c$, there exists some $\epsilon$ and some subsequence that evaluates to values outside the $\epsilon$ open ball around $c$. By $2$, this means that this subsequence is outside some open ball around $(x,y)$, meaning that the subsequence doesn't converge to $(x,y)$, a contradiction. (This is handwavy, but u can fill the gaps)

Comment: The Hausdorff property is obviously necessary for this statement to hold. It is not that obvious that it is sufficient, but it is (under nice properties of the space, which you can think about).

Comment: For C, I _think_ you want Hausdorff first countable spaces for sequences to be sufficient. If you extend to nets, then Hausdorff is probably enough.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you. Thus also (B) is answered.

Comment: Your definition is unusual. Typically, the limit is taken to be a ["deleted limit'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Deleted_versus_non-deleted_limits). Both limits you describe are "non-deleted" (the definitions are indeed consistent, though).

Comment: @BenGrossmann I do not see why my definition is a non-deleted limit. I never mention $f(a,b)$ only some $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Wendell The problem is that you allow $(x,y) = (a,b)$. So, if $f(a,b)$ disagrees with the deleted limit, then the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ condition can't hold. Similarly, the constant sequence $(x_k,y_k) = (a,b)$ converges to $(a,b)$, but $f(x_k,y_k)$ converges to $f(a,b)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Now I understand. A small adjustment is needed in both. For (2) $|(x,y)\ne (a,b)|$ and for (3) the sequence has to not contain $(a,b)$. Thank you

Comment: @Wendell Note that we can strengthen $(3)$ to make it so that $(3) \implies (2)$ if we consider not only sequences but also [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). In particular, a function $f$ over $X$ has a limit of $c$ at $x$ iff for every net $x_{\lambda} \in X \setminus x$ with $x_\lambda \to x$, we have $f(x_{\lambda}) \to c$.